# File upload using blueimp jQuery in coldfusion

Tags: jquery, forms, coldfusion, jquery-file-upload

I have to upload multiple files on a server in ColdFusion, for this I am trying to use blueimp jQuery file upload.
I am new to both cf file upload as well as jQuery. Can someone suggest how to do this?
Along with the file I have other fields too. Based on whether the user has selected a file or not the fields of form are made visible.

So basically i have to perform other jQuery things too on the form along with the file upload.
Please help as soon as possible.

I cannot use form data as this needs to be supported on Ie9, IE10 and IE 11 too.

Comment: `cffile` supports multiple file uploads. See:  https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87505863

Comment: Ya that is fine. But I need to use AJAX for sending the form and when i send the form via $.post the file fields are not passed.